# Should I edit my accepted answer if another answer has a better approach?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, accepted-answer, editing-help

[One of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209490/1047258) is accepted and has a few upvotes as well as a few downvotes(ratio of about 4:1, so 4 upvotes per downvote), basically because [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10268116/1047258) for this question has a better approach(and is a safer way). Should I edit my answer and:

- **Only add a link the other answer** in there?
- Or **add the other answer** as addition to my answer **and link it**?

Or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: You can always leave a comment below your answer, saying that you believe that "answer x is better because..."  Sometimes it can be justified to delete your answer if you find another answer to be far much better. I do this myself now and then.

Comment: I'd only edit it if another answer highlights something /broken/ with your answer that you can fix.  If your answer is fundamentally wrong (or dangerous), you can always delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say leave it be.  Your answer offers another approach or another solution to the problem, and the OP accepts it as an answer to the question.  There's nothing wrong with having more than one approach to a problem.